# Simple utility to display command-line changeable number in Windows' systray

Tags: windows, notification, utility

I'm trying to find some kind of trustworthy utility which does this, and literally ***nothing*** else:

In the "notification area", AKA the part in the bottom-right part of the screen, sort of part of the Taskbar, where it says the current time and date, as well as various icons such as "network connection indicator", "volume mixer" and "remove external hardware", I want there to be an extra "icon" or "area" which simply shows a number, such as:

`0` or `1` or `7` or `36`…

Just a simple number, in the same style as the time/date part.

This number I want to be able to change freely on the command line, with a command such as:

```
"C:\whatever\notificationcounter.exe" --set-value="3"
```

Or:

```
"C:\whatever\notificationcounter.exe" --set-value="0"
```

Whenever I run that command, I want the number to update, silently.

That's all.

As a bonus, this utility could offer the feature that, if I click this number/area, it will run a specified command. However, this is ***not a requirement***.